# Who does the work post-apocalypse in "Kingsman"?

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

In the 2014 film *Kingsman: The Secret Service*, our megalomaniac villain Richmond Valentine plans to

> severely reduce the population of the human race by distributing free sim cards capable of sending a signal which causes people to be uncontrollably violent, killing others at random.

Having done this, he means to

> restart society anew, with a collection of the 'great and the good', made up of celebrities, nobility and politicians. In short, a group of those privileged people who are patently used to having things done for them.

I'm not sure he's thought this through:

> In a post-apocalypse society of the wealthy and privileged, who would know how to produce food? And who would be willing to do menial work such as cleaning, refuse collection and food preparation.

So my question is this:

Does Richmond Valentine have a plan for human society going forward? How is his utopian society supposed to work?

Comment: Is *Kingsman* considered sci-fi? I didn't see the film, but based on the previews it seemed to fall more under the same umbrella as James Bond/ *Mission: Impossible*, which [has been declared off-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/are-questions-about-mission-impossible-on-topic)

Comment: In the glorious spirit of every evil utopian plan ever, all those rich folks would be just so happy to live in such a perfect place that they would gladly take up menial labor in perfect communion with the cause.... or all the security mooks that didn't get shot would trade in their guns for brooms.  I'm not sure which is more short-sighted.

Comment: @JasonBaker It includes a lot of vaguely-plausible technology and a science-driven plot, primarily built around climate change, and the failure of current attempts to curtail it. I'm not sure exactly how this stack-exchange defines science fiction, but I can't see a way in which it doesn't match that topic. 

The parts that aren't science-driven are pure fantasy. 

Perhaps you'd like so suggest an area of Stack Exchange this question would be more suited to?

Comment: @AJFaraday It's unambiguously on-topic at [Movies&TV.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/), but I'm also not 100% sure it's off-topic here, which is why I asked. I'd let the community decide, and a mod can always migrate it if the mob decides against

Comment: @JasonBaker No harm in asking it there, too :)

Comment: It's based on a comic book "The Secret Service" by Mark Miller, if that brings it on topic anymore.

Comment: @AJFaraday Just be sure to not just cross-post the exact same question over there, which is highly discouraged. Pick a place where you want to ask it and ask there.

Comment: Also, the entire plan depended on a form of mind-control delivered via sim chips. It definitely skirts the realm of science-fiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is the main problem with all Mass extinction plots of various levels. The more "science-fictiony" they are, the more that answer becomes "ROBOTS!" but they don't go into that much detail about the overall after-plan in *Kingsman*. Another movie that had a similar premise (the rich and brilliant survive) was *2012*... but they specifically stated that the ability to rebuild society was specifically contained into the 3 Arks alongside historical artifacts.

Back to *Kingsman* - considering the relatively small amount of the elite in comparison to the rest of the world, as long as they have the people to operate a representative portion of the largely-mechanized American Agribusiness, they should be okay if they relocate and have a handful of John Deere higher-ups survive.

As displayed by Hart in the church scene, there would still be some people left after the mass hysteria chips go off... those whom are the strongest fighters or most reclusive. Although this is not explicitly stated in the movie, there may have even been a population of people selected to become servants in this plan, such as third/fourth world countries, or populations that deliberately eschewed technology (Amish, nomadic Bhotiyas, off-grid people groups, etcetera). Those would be undoubtedly collected and subjugated by the world elites, starting the process that started this mess all over.